# Model Binding DBContext disposed on page load

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, webforms

I been struggling to understand why i get a DBContext disposed error when i add a .Skip() and .Take() linq methods to a query. I have a version that works well, that does not have the above mentioned methods, and just can't get a grasp on what makes the difference.

Here is the two methods, that return data to a Model Binded GridView's select method:

```
// This is the method that causes the DBContext disposed exception

            public IQueryable<ProductCategory> GetCategoriesByPage(int pageNumber, int pageSize)
        {
            using (var dataModel = new MagicDayEntities())
            {
                var pagedCategories = (from categories in dataModel.ProductCategories
                                       orderby categories.CategoryName ascending
                                       select categories)
                        .Skip((pageSize - 1) * pageNumber)
                        .Take(pageSize);
                pagedCategories.ToList().AsQueryable();
                return pagedCategories;
            }
        }

//This method returns the data properly without error

        public IQueryable<ProductCategory> GetAllCategories()
        {
            using (var dataModel = new MagicDayEntities())
            {
                var allCategories = (from categories in dataModel.ProductCategories
                                     orderby categories.CategoryName ascending
                                     select categories)
                                     .ToList()
                                     .AsQueryable();
                return allCategories;
            }
        }
```

In my knowledge the ToList() should force the query to run, and overcomes the lazy loadings behavior and enables the DbContext to be in a "using" statement, which is a requirement.

Here are the exception details:

```
The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below. 

Stack Trace: 


[InvalidOperationException: The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.]
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() +4249201
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) +40
   System.Linq.Queryable.Count(IQueryable`1 source) +196
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.QueryableHelpers.CountHelper(IQueryable`1 queryable) +48

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +160
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +101
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ModelDataSourceView.ProcessSelectMethodResult(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceSelectResultProcessingOptions selectResultProcessingOptions, ModelDataMethodResult result) +249
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ModelDataSourceView.GetSelectMethodResult(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) +92
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ModelDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) +15
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +22
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ModelDataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +80
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +143
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +74
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind() +9
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +114
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.CreateChildControls() +75
   System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +92
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +42
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +883


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.1586.0
```

Could someone help me out, and shed some light on the cause of this exception?
Thanks in advance.
Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You execute your query by calling `ToList`:

```
pagedCategories.ToList().AsQueryable();
```

And then ignore the result and return the original query, which will be executed when your view binds to it:

```
return pagedCategories;
```

Change to return the list:

```
return pagedCategories.ToList().AsQueryable();
```

I'd also suggest changing the return type to `IEnumerable<ProductCategory>` and removing the calls to `AsQueryable`. It doesn't really make any sense to do that.

Comment: Exactly one you have forced data in the memory then `IQueryable` has no significance +1

Comment: Thank you for point it out, once i shifted the .ToList() call it worked.